# Teradata TTU Installation on MACOS...TPT not working

Tags: macos, teradata

I've installed Teradata TTU on my mac. After installation BTEQ works, but TPT does not work.

$tbuild
-bash: tbuild: command not found

Comment: this is says that `tbuild` is not available anywhere on your `$PATH`. What location on the filesystem did you use for the install? What is the output when you run `type -a bteq`? You might want to try running `find /Library /Applications -name "tbuild"` (Note the space between  `/Library` and `/Applications`, they are 2 separate arguments, we're searching *both* locations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS X, the TTU "Standard Install" includes only ODBC, BTEQ, and TDWallet. To install TPT you must use the "Customize" option.

Comment: I did not see the customize option when downloading or installing the package. How and where do I get the custom option?

Comment: Are you using the latest 16.20 version? After you double-click the TeradataToolsAndUtilities...pkg file, you should see the Welcome screen, then License agreement, then have the option to Install, Change Location, or Customize. See the documentation [here](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/Up~1NgRhWUPoVMXdOdY4jw/0zZ7DJQn2sHCeNFftX6sfg).

Comment: Thank you so much! I missed that small treasure link!